# Badge Dates on User Profile should show the Year once the Year is over

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, badges

In the example screenshot taken from my Arqade user profile summary, I earned the Socratic badge on [November 16<sup>th</sup>, 2021](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/288/socratic?userid=163757).  But all it shows on the summary page is "Nov 16".  When I see this, it makes me think it would be for this year, but obviously November hasn't occurred yet. I could also see people mistaking this for *November 2016*.

[image: badges]

Additionally, this is inconsistent with how other parts of the page show the dates.  For example, see the red underlined dates in the "Questions" summary, while the badges circled in blue show only the month/day.

[image: inconsistencies]

The summary page should either show the year all the time for the badge summary, or at least once the year the badge was earned has ended, the year should be displayed.  I am guessing the way this currently works is the year needs to be over, and then the month in question must also have started in the subsequent year.

Comment: Yeah there is a logic bug there that is calculating whether a year has passed instead of using what the current year is I think.

Comment: Just in case someone thinks it's OK to make the user logically deduce that the year is 2019 because the date couldn't be Nov 16 2022--it is not clear whether the date is being calculated incorrectly, or simply truncated (because the dates are right-justified). And I am very proud of myself for not launching into a rant about how misguided it is to pin two pieces of information that are supposed to go together to opposite sides of the reading area. The easiest way to prevent bugs is to design so that it is obvious when something is wrong.

Comment: Not showing the year when the date is less than one year ago is how Stack Exchange has shown dates for a very long time. That they are including the year in some dates when the date is less than a year ago is the new thing. Personally, I'd prefer that they were consistent and always showed the year, but that's a change that would need to be propagated (hopefully they have a utility function doing the render which could just be changed), but it would affect, and thus need to be tested in, a lot of places all over the sites. (Oh, right, this is SE, they don't need to test it.)