# In September I am told about a badge received in December... which year?

Tags: bug, profile-page, badges

What does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469208/trejder) mean:

[image]

When did I (will I :) earn this badge? It is September, December is still ahead of us.

Is it Dec 2, 2022? Only (due to a bug?) year is omitted?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, mine is a dupe of the mentioned one. Sorry for not enough research.

Comment: I think [this question that I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377227/badge-dates-on-user-profile-should-show-the-year-once-the-year-is-over) is a better duplicate but its the same issue (though mine is a feature-request really)

Comment: Doesn't hovering the mouse cursor over it (or the equivalent) display the absolute date (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum no, there's no tooltip for the badge dates in profile, can be a good feature request to ask adding them.

Comment: @TimothyG. added that one as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of writing, the [fourth page of 'All actions' from your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469208/trejder?tab=activity&sort=all&page=4) provides the answer:

[image: Snippet of 'All Actions' showing the badge was awarded in December 2022]

This shows that the badge was awarded to you on Dec 2, 2022. It's likely that the way this is shown as 'Dec 2' in the badges area of your profile is *by design* as it's within the last year.